# How does the Tech Support know my exact location given my location services is turned off?

Tags: find-my-iphone, geolocation

When I logged in to support.apple.com and search for the nearest service provider, it said it is not possible, as I expected. My location services are turned off since Day 1. There is no particular reason, I just do not need that for the device in question. Only one device is added to the particular account, and I never really carry this device to anywhere.

I remember to have search up my zip code once (on the support website to get the nearest provider) which probably might be available to them (albeit unlikely), or they probably have the data because of the details provided by Apple Store from where I purchased it.

It freaks me out, since I do not see something that they see. Not because they have the details.

Comment: How would they know my IP address? (this could be dumb, but I did not send anything in particular). Also my IP address location is different.

Comment: How did you find out that Tech Support knows your location? How exact is exact actually (GPS details, city, region)?

Comment: @nohillside Well they suggested me a service center in my exact zip code, which indicates that they know my location in some form.

Comment: For my device support. I logged in to support.apple.com (and then chat) from my Windows laptop however, that does not have the location service turned on either. It is the usual tech support that comes with your device. I purchased the device from an Apple Store (offline), which I mentioned already. It's a Wifi only device.

Comment: Maybe I am stupid and all but when one is “logged in” then service provider knows “everything” user provided while signing up.

Answer (score 3):

There could be multiple sources that Apple has received your location from.

Even if you do not think about it, your IP addresses is actually transmitted to the web server (Apple's server) every time you load up a web site. In many cases an IP address can pinpoint your location to a specific city or similar. This would be enough for them to able to suggest a store in a specific zip code.

In addition WiFi-enabled devices without GPS are still able to find their location from other sources - for example the names (SSIDs) of WiFi access point the device "sees". When it is moved around, it is possible to assemble a list of known access points which can then be translated into a position by an online server. For example the cars that Google uses to gather data for Google Maps also collects WiFI SSID information for this purpose.

If you're especially worried that Apple support knows your location, I would just ask them where they have your address from. If you're located within the European Union, you have rights based on the GDPR that would ensure that they're obligated to tell you that they have this information on file.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of every page on Apple's site where your location is shown, at least in the UK, is a footnote explaining where Apple gets your location from.

> <sup>††</sup> […] We found your location using your IP address or because you entered it during a previous visit to Apple.